# How to set a range of cells equal to a separate cell?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, array-formulas

I'm working on Google Sheets with baseball statistics.  I have one sheet that has the team names going across row 1 & underneath each team name; I have the players names.
I also have a second spreadsheet which has players names and all their statistics for a certain time frame.  The issue is that on the second spreadsheet it only has the players names and doesn't tell me what team they play for?
Is there a formula that will search the first sheet for the players name and display the team name in a separate column next to the players name on the second sheet?

Comment: Yes, using some combination of `index`, `match`, `hlookup`, and `vlookup` can work. I'm sure a clever `sumproduct` could even work.

Comment: Do you know what that formula would look like? @tehhowch

Comment: Post a copy of your spreadsheet, or at least a couple of screenshoots to let everybody see what your data looks like. Then we can maybe help you with a specific formula.